# Crear test al hacer click en botón de modal

Tags: angular, test, testing, jasmine, karma

Llevo ya un buen rato metido en esto y no veo la luz. ¿Cómo puedo testear esta función?

```
eliminar(event: Event): void {
    const element = event.currentTarget as Element;
    const primary= element.classList.contains('delete');

    if (primary) {
      this.deleteDraft();
    } else {
      this.closeDraft();
    }
  }
```

Se ejecuta cuando hacemos click en el botón eleminar de un modal.

Estoy testeando con Jasmin, Karma en un proyecto con Angular 11 y node 14.

Cualquier breve indicación para ver como afrontarlo es de agradecer.

Comment: Por qué no muestras el código que tienes con Jasmin

Comment: Básicamente por que lo que tengo ahora mismo no aportaría nada de valor a la pregunta.